# Compare two dataframes based off of key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, analytics

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, which have the exact same columns and most of the time the same values for each key.

> ```
> Country   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   Key
> Argentina xylo    262 4632    0   0   26.12   2   0   Argentinaxylo
> Argentina phone   6860    155811  48  0   4375.87 202 0   Argentinaphone
> Argentina land    507 1803728 2   117 7165.810566 3   154 Argentinaland
> Australia xylo    7650    139472  69  0   16858.42    184 0   Australiaxylo
> Australia mink    1284    2342788 1   0   39287.71    53  0   Australiamink
>
>
> Country   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   Key
> Argentina xylo    262 4632    0   0   26.12   2   0   Argentinaxylo
> Argentina phone   6860    155811  48  0   4375.87 202 0   Argentinaphone
> Argentina land    507 1803728 2   117 7165.810566 3   154 Argentinaland
> Australia xylo    7650    139472  69  0   16858.42    184 0   Australiaxylo
> Australia mink    1284    2342788 1   0   39287.71    53  0   Australiamink
> ```

I want a snippet that compares the keys (key = column Country + column A) in each dataframe against each other and calculates the percent difference for each column B-H, if there is any. If there isn't, output nothing.

Comment: does `Country` column matter? and also, column `A` is string type, what do you mean by `percent difference`?

Comment: yes, it's technically part of the key...edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, the below given code may help you to solve your problem. I have compared both datasets based on the Key column data and generate the difference of their (B-H) columns respectively. Thereafter, having the difference in percentage, I just have merge on the both datasets on Key column, compare the difference and have the final output in df3diff column of df3 dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Argentina', 'xylo', 262 ,4632,    0 ,  0  , 26.12  , 2 , 0  , 'Argentinaxylo']
                    ,['Argentina', 'phone',6860,155811 , 48 , 0   ,4375.87 ,202, 0  , 'Argentinaphone']
                    ,['Argentina', 'land', 507 ,1803728, 2  , 117 ,7165.810,566, 3  , '154 Argentinaland']
                    ,['Australia', 'xylo', 7650,139472 , 69 , 0   ,16858.42,184, 0  , 'Australiaxylo']
                    ,['Australia', 'mink', 1284,2342788, 1  , 0   ,39287.71, 53,  0 , 'Australiamink']]
                   ,columns=['Country',   'A',   'B',   'C',   'D',   'E',   'F',   'G',   'H',   'Key'])

df1['df1BH'] = (df1['B']-df1['H'])/100.00
print(df1)


df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Argentina', 'xylo', 262 ,4632   , 0 ,  0   ,26.12   ,2  , 0   ,'Argentinaxylo']
                    ,['Argentina', 'phone',6860,155811 , 48,  0   ,4375.87 ,202, 0   ,'Argentinaphone']
                    ,['Argentina', 'land', 507 ,1803728, 2 ,  117 ,7165.810,566, 3   ,'154 Argentinaland']
                    ,['Australia', 'xylo', 97650,139472 , 69,  0   ,96858.42,184, 0   ,'Australiaxylo']
                    ,['Australia', 'mink', 1284,2342788, 1 ,  0   ,39287.71, 53,  0  ,'Australiamink']]
                   ,columns=['Country',   'A',   'B',   'C',   'D',   'E',   'F',   'G',   'H',   'Key'])
df2['df2BH'] = (df2['B']-df2['H'])/100.00
print(df2)



df3 = pd.merge(df1[['Key','df1BH']],df2[['Key','df2BH']], on=['Key'],how='outer')
df3['df3diff'] = df3['df1BH'] - df3['df2BH']
print(df3)
```

**Output:**

```
                 Key  df1BH   df2BH  df3diff
0      Argentinaxylo   2.62    2.62      0.0
1     Argentinaphone  68.60   68.60      0.0
2  154 Argentinaland   5.04    5.04      0.0
3      Australiaxylo  76.50  976.50   -900.0
4      Australiamink  12.84   12.84      0.0
```